# SELECT2 ajax - preloaded options

Tags: ajax, jquery, drupal, jquery-select2

At the moment I have a dropdown that works with ajax request to the server, but it also be nice to attach some default options on select2 initialization.  With *initSelection* function I only can attach one option, but not full preloaded array. I was also trying to use *data* option but it's doesn't work too. 
Here is my code:

```
$("#address-select2").select2({
    placeholder: "--- ' . t('I\'ll add new address') . ' ---",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: { 
        url: "/ajax/address_autocomplete/from",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return {results: data.addresses};
        }
    }, 
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        $.ajax("/ajax/address_autocomplete/from/100", {
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            callback(data.addresses[0]);
        });
    },
    formatResult: function (address) {
        return "<span class=\"dropdown-element\">" + address.text + "</span>";
    },
    formatSelection: function (address) {
        return address.text;
    },
    formatNoMatches: function () { return "' . t('No result found!') . '";},
    formatSearching: function () { return "' . t('Searching...') . '"; },
    formatLoadMore: function (pageNumber) { return "' . t('Loading results...') . '"; },
    dropdownCssClass : "bigdrop"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please do not pass `callback(data.addresses[0]);`
please pass array directly like this `callback(data.addresses);`
it should work i have done it.